# How to check if a factor variable has only the levels I want?

Tags: r, factors, levels

What's the simplest way to verify a factor variable has the levels I want to?

```
# I want to make sure a factor variable has 'FP', 'TP' but nothing else

a <- factor(c('TP','TP','FP')) # Return TRUE
b <- factor(c('TP')) # Return TRUE
c <- factor(c('TP', '1234')) # Return FALSE
```

Comment: @Ronak Shah TRUE or FALSE is good enough

Comment: Depending on what you're doing, you may not want your second example to return TRUE.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can use `all` with `%in%`

```
all(levels(a) %in% c("FP", "TP"))
#[1] TRUE
all(levels(b) %in% c("FP", "TP"))
#[1] TRUE
all(levels(c) %in% c("FP", "TP"))
#[1] FALSE
```

---

Just to avoid the repetition of code or in case if there are more levels that we need to check

```
checkFactor <- c("FP", "TP")
all(levels(a) %in% checkFactor)
#[1] TRUE
all(levels(b) %in% checkFactor)
#[1] TRUE
all(levels(c) %in% checkFactor)
#[1] FALSE
```

Answer (score 1):

Yet another way to do the same:

```
check.factor.levels <- function(expected, actual) {
  length(setdiff(actual, expected)) == 0  
}

expected <- c('FP', 'TP')
check.factor.levels(expected, levels(a))
#[1] TRUE
check.factor.levels(expected, levels(b))
#[1] TRUE
check.factor.levels(expected, levels(c))
#[1] FALSE
```

Comment: yes but i thought OP just wants a one-way check (the actual levels are in the expected levels, but the expected levels may contain some other levels, e.g., consider the testcase b).